# How to group data in ionic 5?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've a problem here in Ionic 5 where I want to order some products by their category. I've read and it seems that with pipes I can achieve this, but Im not getting the idea how it works.

My JSON:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test",
            "items": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Test 2",
            "items": 2
        }
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "category_id": 1,
            "name": "Vin",
            "description": "fsdfsdfsdfsd",
            "price": 25,
            "discounted_price": 22,
            "weight": 244,
            "estimated_prep_time": "00:20:30",
            "image": null
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "category_id": 14,
            "name": "test",
            "description": "sdfadfafd",
            "price": 22,
            "discounted_price": 21,
            "weight": 500,
            "estimated_prep_time": "00:20:30",
            "image": null
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "category_id": 14,
            "name": "Test",
            "description": "lorem ipsum dolo sit met",
            "price": 25,
            "discounted_price": null,
            "weight": 2555,
            "estimated_prep_time": "00:20:30",
            "image": null
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to filter them by 'Category ID', so they can be something like this:

Category 1

- Item 2
- Item 5

Category 2

- Item 1
- Item 3

Category 3

- Item 4
- Item 5

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for ?

```
let output = data.categories.map(category => {
  return {...category, items: data.items.filter(item => {
    return item.category_id == category.id;
  })};
});
```

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "category_id": 1,
        "name": "Vin",
        "description": "fsdfsdfsdfsd",
        "price": 25,
        "discounted_price": 22,
        "weight": 244,
        "estimated_prep_time": "00:20:30",
        "image": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Test 2",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "category_id": 14,
        "name": "test",
        "description": "sdfadfafd",
        "price": 22,
        "discounted_price": 21,
        "weight": 500,
        "estimated_prep_time": "00:20:30",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "category_id": 14,
        "name": "Test",
        "description": "lorem ipsum dolo sit met",
        "price": 25,
        "discounted_price": null,
        "weight": 2555,
        "estimated_prep_time": "00:20:30",
        "image": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```